# download source code

Tags: ros, source, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it posible to download the source code of the project?

I am trying to extend it.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9410/download-source-code/) by [yonnitempo](https://answers.ros.org/users/288/yonnitempo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which project do you mean? ROS is a combination of different repositories each hosting their packages ([Repository list](http://www.ros.org/browse/repo_list.php)) you can get an [introduction here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) and its [concepts](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Concepts)

The core packages can be found in the willow garage repository and on the Ros code site:

- [Code.ros.org](https://code.ros.org/gf/)

You can look at the [get involved site](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you install [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall#Installation) you can then use the [roslocate](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslocate) tool. To get the source link for a given package or stack, all you would have to do then is something like

```
roslocate uri <package_or_stack_name>
```

and it will output the full URI to the source repository for that package or stack.

Note that the code probably won't be very useful to you unless you have a working [ROS installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2